# How to change particular order number in magento

Tags: magento-1.8, sales-order

I have created new order in magento store which id is  **order number#100000434**.
I need to change order id to  number like **100000433**.

How can I do this...?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Found this, https://magecomp.com/magento-custom-order-number.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to phpmyadmin->Database->sql commend

1. `SELECT increment_id FROM sales_flat_order where increment_id='100000434'`
2. `UPDATE sales_flat_order SET increment_id = '100000433' WHERE sales_flat_order.increment_id = '100000434'`

Answer (score 2):

Why you what to change the order id !?

If you change  **order number#100000434** to **100000433** it may give you duplicate order id error, Because in magento order id is auto increment,if you have **100000434** order id means previous order id will be **100000433** ...

Comment: thank for reply me @Sheshgiri Anvekar. Actually I was deleted **100000433** order that's why am creating it manually.